# adjusting heights of individual subplots in matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

if I have a series of subplots with one column and many rows, i.e.:

```
plt.subplot(4, 1, 1) # first subplot
plt.subplot(4, 1, 2) # second subplot
# ...
```

how can I adjust the height of the first N subplots? For example, if I have 4 subplots, each on its own row, I want all of them to have the same width but the first 3 subplots to be shorter, i.e. have their y-axes be smaller and take up less of the plot than the y-axis of the last plot in the row.  How can I do this?

thanks.

Comment: Use the [AxesGrid toolkit](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#axesgrid).

Comment: Use tight_layout. This link has good examples: http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html . To make it work, you need to change the figsize e.g.  `plt.figure(figsize=(10, 1.5*plotsToPlot))` where `plotsToPlot` is the number of subplots on one figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. The most basic (and least flexible) way is to just call something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(6,1,1)
plt.subplot(6,1,2)
plt.subplot(6,1,3)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
```

Which will give you something like this:
[image: Unequal Subplots]

However, this isn't very flexible.  If you're using matplotlib >= 1.0.0, look into using [GridSpec](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/gridspec.html).  It's quite nice, and is a much more flexible way of laying out subplots.

Comment: I believe this answer to sub-optimal,the answer below should be the accepted one

Comment: @user2422503 - Note that date and the reference to exactly what the answer below suggests.  At that time, subplot2grid/GridSpec/etc was very new and most people were using a matplotlib release that didn't contain it.  Therefore, I showed the more widely-available solution and gave a pointed to the newer, cleaner solution.

Comment: @ Joe Kington , I am sorry

Answer (score 24):

Even though this question is old, I was looking to answer a very similar question.  @Joe's reference to [AxesGrid](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#axesgrid), was the answer to my question, and has **very** straightforward usage, so I wanted to illustrate that functionality for completeness.

[AxesGrid](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#axesgrid) functionality provides the ability create plots of different size and place them very specifically, via the [`subplot2grid`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) functionality:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((m, n), (row_1, col_1), colspan = width)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((m, n), (row_2, col_2), rowspan = height)

ax1.plot(...)
ax2.plot(...)
```

Note that the max values for `row_n`,`col_n` are `m-1` and `n-1` respectively, as zero indexing notation is used.

Specifically addressing the question, if there were 5 total subplots, where the last subplot has twice the height as the others, we could use `m=6`.

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 1), (0, 0))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 1), (1, 0))
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 1), (2, 0))
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 1), (3, 0))
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 1), (4, 0), rowspan=2)
plt.show()
```

[image: Last Graph, twice the height]

Comment: thanks for posting -- I needed to do this and it is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: This is really easy and works much better than the accepted answer